# Insertion syntax for regex in Notepad++ or Perl

Tags: regex, insert, insertion

Shortform: searching:
 **"{,[0-9][0-9],"** inserting Space+00... getting replaced string segment:
 **"{,SPACE00[0-9][0-9],"** or other so-garbaged data for found [0-9][0-9] sequence ... so how do I search with a regex and insert in the middle???

Longform question:

I'm trying to do a series of simple character insertions -- digits actually -- in a series of mixed model CSV profiling data (five files each with different model parameters, several hundred lines each).

I'm visually challenged and desire to insert padding characters to columize data, so I can focus on tweaking key values, not keeping place data file to data file.
This need where the CSV data lines format are:

*Variable_symbolic-name**,{##,##,** ... ('Set of CSV Numerical Data lists' ...},\n*

**an actual data line:**

61,parameter17,{,70,6,1,-1,3, 00,0,0,0,0,},,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**to be morphed to:**

61,parameter17,\t\t{, 0070,6,1,-1,3, 00,0,0,0,0,},,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Give or take a tab character to align all the { numeric field starts...

I've found searching: **"{,[0-9][0-9],"** failed but **"\{,[0-9][0-9],"** succeeds for **the find part** of the **search and replace** operation... but have hit a proverbial brick wall in how to do *the actual replace (with an insert)* of such a short length. (Obviously with so many parameters and files, I'm moving cautiously!)

However, [This Perl Help tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) leaves me in the dark as to how to keep the found ranges and insert padding before (Space, zero, zero to be specific if positive, '-00' if negative) In short, I need to know how to insert 2-3 places in the replace field in Notepad++... ***and retain the original data*** without prejudicing it!

Articles herein have cited replacing paragraphs and lines, adding newlines, etc. but this simple insertion alteration seems too simple for you all. But it's been several hours of frustration for me!

Thanks! // Frank

Resolved: 
Good news: **({,)([0-9][0-9],)** and **\1 xx\2** works fine as does **({,)(@[0-9][0-9],)** and replacing with **\1 xx@\2** ... whether or not tabs are utilized. Obviously the key was **([0-9][0-9],)** which included the discrimination of the comma... though I have no idea why that seemed to fail an hour ago with trials made using Sobrinho's help. Must have not tried the sequence. Thanks all!

Comment: In Perl (and most everything), `{,[0-9][0-9],` matches `{,25,` There is no need to escape the `{`. It is Not a metachar in this context. So, I wonder why you say it "failed".

Comment: It fails because it's not discriminating between {,25, and {,2534,... as you can see in the other thread the problem is place discrimination and replacing the found substrings with an inserted substring by length. Trying to create neat columns in CSV with a wildly variable left column length. Tab does a lot, but wastes page width. I can live with that computers input streams faster than I can read, and we're looking at a change of only 10% of length in a few kilobytes file. File min length is likely 4K or more so no cost at all. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this deserves a correction. '{' in Notepad++ sets off a numeric count so '\{' was necessary for the find when regex was enabled. Other search modes the '{' worked fine. // Frank

Comment: I thought you were using Perl. Don't know what Notepad++ uses for a regex engine, but its a poor choice of custom chars, if it has to dither something like `a{1,}` and `a{,1}`. The first is a quantifier for 'a`, the second is all literal. Might be the old BRE or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try to type this in the search box:

```
(.+)(\{,[0-9][0-9].*)
```

And in the replace:

```
\1\t\t\2
```

When you have things between parenthesis, they are "stored" by Notepad++ and can be reused in the replace box.

The order of the parenthesis starts with one and are accessed as \1, \2, ...

Comment: Your solution was too greedy and failed to isolate around the ,{,  However, **(.+)(\{,)([0-9][0-9].*)** and  **\1\t\t\2 00\3** works fine on short 1st digits, but failed on column data with four  digits... let me play more. Thanks-got me off center.

Comment: Good, I am happy that you understood how the "saving" and "using" works, now you will probably solve by yourself! :)

Comment: Actually failing in that hope. Can you suggest how to discriminate against adding padding before three and four digit places. If I do this SAR on **',(4924,'** bad things will happen... likely the second of either: *',{49 0024, or ',{ 004924,'* **(.+)(\{,**)+(**[0-9][0-9].)** is still picking up lines with 3 and 4 digits, and there will be a need for similar changes on one digit-comma.  Place counts aren't an apparent strength of regex parsing, it would seem.

Comment: Ok, try this then, search for: ^(.+)(\{,[0-9][0-9].*)$
Replace by: \1\t\t\2

^ matches the start of the line, while $ matches the end

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Start of line versus start of numeric data seems should not make a difference. So end of \1 field is ,{, in all cases. What is failing in the search is place count of two numbers then the comma. The second field ([0-9][0-9],) is not just picking up ##, but also ###, and ####. Perhaps if I added a dummy with a global SAR on ,{, to pad a non-sense delimiter such as to get ,{,@ before the numbers? Appreciate the help. Don't understand the $ operator. My eyes have trouble reading... period, so this is really good. I haven't programmed in 20 yrs so this is tough sledding.

Comment: I think i saw a flaw, try this: (.+,)(\{,[0-9][0-9].*)

Check that i put another comma in the first parenthesis, and this will make the \1 to be in the { charachter and not in the ,{

Answer (score 0):

You will need a backreference here, meaning something which, in the replace part, will be equal to what you have matched.

Usually, the whole matched part is stored in the `$0` backreference. (You can get `$1` with a capture group too, and up to `$2` with two capture groups, etc)

Back to your question, you could try this:

Find:

```
(\{,)([0-9][0-9],)
```

Replace by:

```
\t\t$1 00$2
```

This will insert two tab characters before the part that matched `\{,[0-9][0-9],` (or in other words, replace the part that matched by 2 tab characters and what you matched), then put the first captured part (`{,`) and then the space and double 0's and then the second captured part, the two digits and following comma.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aO8rD8)

Comment: This was tagged as Perl, $0 won't work in Perl. See my answer.

Comment: @justintime The user mentioned that he is doing this in Notepad++, which supports the backreference syntax `$0` fully.

Comment: Can either of you translate to what I've added at Lauro Wolff Valente Sobrinho's answer. Don't know what the difference is between his \1, \2... and your $1, $2... I'm fairly clueless about software these days.

Comment: (\{,)([0-9][0-9],) this nesting may bear fruit... I'll be back after some more trial and error.

Comment: @user3254047 `\1` is equivalent to `$1`. Most languages are moving from the (older) syntax for backreferences from `\1` to `$1` and in many cases, both are supported. As for your comments, I find them a tad hard to understand. You can use backticks (`) to format code and prevent style markdown.

Comment: Good news: **(\{,)([0-9][0-9],)** and **\1 xx\2** works fine as does **(\{,)(@[0-9][0-9],)** and replacing with **\1 xx@\2** ... whether or not tabs are utilized. Obviously the key was **([0-9][0-9],)** which included the discrimination of the comma... though I have no idea why that seemed to fail an hour ago with Sobrinho's trials. Thanks all!

Comment: @user3254047 Sobrinho used `.*` which is meant to match any character except newlines, and this thus allows matches of 2 or more digits, instead of 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged it as Perl, so here is how you do it in Perl ...

I prefer to use lookahead assertions rather than backreferences

```
s/(?= {,[0-9][0-9], ) /\t\t/x
```

Alternatively, `$&` contains the matched string (`$0` is something different)

```
s/ {,[0-9][0-9],  /\t\t$&/x
```

Comment: I used Perl as it wouldn't let me use tag 'regex-insertion' ... I don't have a high enough rating which is fair enough given I haven't programmed seriously since the early nineties. If you guys can shed any light on how to isolate on the pre and post substrings as discussed with Lauro Wolff Valente Sobrinho, I can really use a fix. I think I opened these file up over three hours ago!  Thanks from this old hardware engineer. Frank!